# Determine a basis for the Lie-Algebra $\text{sp}(\text{2n},\mathbb{C})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider the Lie Group $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})=\{g\in\text{Mat}_{2n}\mid\ J=g^TJg\}$  where $J=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1_n \\
 -1_n & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
 $. 
The corresponding Lie Algebra is $\text{sp}(\text{2n},\mathbb{C})=\{g\in\text{Mat}_{2n}\mid\ g^TJ+Jg=0\}$.

How do I determine a basis for the Lie-Algebra $\text{sp}(\text{2n},\mathbb{C})$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, write down the general matrix $S=\begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{pmatrix}$ then, look at the equation $S^TJ+JS=0$, ie
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1_n \\
 -1_n & 0 
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1_n \\
 -1_n & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{pmatrix}=0$$
Solving it blockwise would then give you $S=\begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\
C & -A^T 
\end{pmatrix}$, where $B$ and $C$ are symmetric, ie $B=B^T,C=C^T$. So your basis is a free choice on $A$, symmetric $B$ and $C$.

By the way, a great book on Lie Algebras is Erdmann-Wildon's Lie Algebras.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and recommendation for the book! Youre the man!